# How to describe the coupling between $\mu$ and $\nu$?

Tags: calculus, probability, measure-theory

Here is the definition of the coupling:

[image]

In measure theory, coupling μ and ν means constructing a measure π on X ×Y such that π admits μ and ν as marginals on X and Y respectively.

Here is the definition of deterministic coupling:

[image]

Comment: This definition seems to rely on some prior definition of what a coupling $(X,Y)$ means.  Your question also suggests that there is some other definition that applies to coupling between distributions, rather than between random variables.

Comment: @Michael I have added it. But the definition of coupling is just the normal definition.

Comment: @Michael Does not the coupling of two random variables same as the coupling of two distributions?

Comment: I don't know. I do not understand Definition 1.1, I do not know what law(X) means or how it relates to $\mu$. Definition 1.2 seems inconsistent with 1.1 since $\mathcal{X}$ is a general sample space, perhaps $\mathcal{X} = \{green, red\}$, while random variables $X$, $Y$ have real values. So $T:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathcal{Y}$ (which means the domain of $T$ is a set of colors) does not make sense with $Y=T(X)$ (which means the domain of $T$ is a set of real numbers).  I also would feel more comfortable with a probability space including a sigma algebra: $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not you are talking about "random variables" or "random elements," and whether or not you feel compelled to specify the sigma algebras,  I believe you are asking "the wrong question": If you already have random variables $X, Y$ on the same probability space that satisfy  $Y=T(X)$ for some measurable function $T$, **then you are done**.  The difficult question is if you are given two different CDF functions, can you define $X$ and $Y$ on the same probability space such that $X$ has the first CDF, $Y$ has the second CDF, and $Y=T(X)$ for some measurable $T$? (not always)

Comment: @Michael coupling μ and ν means constructing a measure π on X ×Y such that π admits μ and ν as marginals on X and Y respectively.

Comment: @Michael You can take the sigma-algebra as the Borel sigma algebra.

Comment: That does not make sense: What is the "Borel sigma algebra" on $\{green, red\}$? On a general set?

Comment: @Michael No, my settings is that we have $X\sim Uniform[0,1]$ and $Y=(X-0.1)^3$. Can we find a coupling of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: @Michael We take two Borel probability measures on $R$.

Comment: You may want to reread my comment (on inconsistency between Definitions 1.1 and 1.2) that shows how if $\mathcal{X}$ is a general set it does not make sense to assume $\mathcal{X}$ is a subset of the real numbers.  Also the comment on **then you are done** (in terms of already having $Y=T(X)$, there is nothing more to do).

Comment: @Michael Ok, why there is nothing to do after $Y=T(X)$? The coupling should be $(X,Y)$? Do you mean the coupling is $(X,Y)=(X, T(X))$?

Comment: @Michael For that example $X\sim Uniform[0,1]$ and $Y=(X-0,1)^3$. Define Borel probability measures $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ and $\nu$ on $[0.001, 0.729]$.

Comment: Yes, any two random variables $X$ and $Y$ on the same probability space can also be viewed as a random vector $(X,Y)$ that itself already defines a coupling between the distribution of $X$ and the distribution of $Y$.  If it just so happens that $Y=T(X)$ for some measurable $T$, then that is in fact even a deterministic coupling.  The reverse questions are more important: Given two distributions, (i) Can we define a coupling $(X,Y)$? (yes trivially by imposing  independence via the product measure); (ii) Can we define a deterministic coupling? (this is harder and cannot always be done).

Comment: In your example $X \sim Uniform[0,1]$ and $Y=T(X)$ for some measurable $T:[0,1]\rightarrow [a,b]$ then $(X,Y)$ is a deterministic coupling between the distributions $\mu$ of $X$ and $v$ of $Y$.  Specifically $\mu(A)=P[X \in A]$ for all $A \in \mathcal{B}([0,1])$, $v(B)=P[T(X)\in B]$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}([a,b])$.

Comment: @Michael Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer that summarizes my above comments:

Any two random variables $X$ and $Y$ on the same probability space can also be viewed as a random vector $(X,Y)$ that itself already defines a coupling between the distribution of $X$ and the distribution of $Y$. If it just so happens that $Y=T(X)$ for some measurable function $T$ then $(X,Y)$ is in fact a deterministic coupling.

In your example $X \sim Uniform([0,1])$ and $Y=T(X)$ for some measurable $T:[0,1]\rightarrow [a,b]$ (given some real numbers $a,b$ with $a<b$), then indeed $(X,Y)$ is already a deterministic coupling between the distribution $\mu$ of $X$ and the distribution $v$ of $Y$.  Specifically
\begin{align}
&\mu(A) = P[X \in A] \quad \forall A \in \mathcal{B}([0,1])\\
&v(B) = P[T(X) \in B] \quad \forall B \in \mathcal{B}([a,b])
\end{align}

---

On the reverse situation: Given two distributions $\mu$ and $v$, there might be many ways of constructing a random vector $(X,Y)$ such that $X$ has distribution $\mu$ and $Y$ has distribution $v$.  The simplest way is to impose independence between $X$ and $Y$ via the product measure. However, we can then ask if there is a **deterministic** coupling (so that $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily independent). The answer is "not necessarily."  For example if $(X,Y)$ is a random vector where $X$ takes values in the set $\{0,1,2\}$ equally likely, and $Y$ takes values in the set $\{0,1\}$ equally likely, it is not possible to write $X=T(Y)$ or $Y=T(X)$ for some function $T$.

A key interesting result on stochastic coupling between random variables is this: Let $X:\Omega_1\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $W:\Omega_2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be random variables on potentially different probability spaces $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{F}_1, P_1)$ and $(\Omega_2, \mathcal{F}_2, P_2)$ that satisfy
$$P_1[X>x]\leq P_2[W>x]\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \quad (*)$$
Then there is a random variable $Y:\Omega_1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (on the same probability space as $X$) such that  $X(\omega)\leq Y(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega_1$, and $Y$ has the same distribution as $W$ (so $P_1[Y>y]=P_2[W>y]$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$). If (*) holds we say that $X$ is stochastically less than or equal to $W$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I ask what do you mean in the first sentence? In my example, $X$ and $Y=T(X)$ are defined on the same probability space $(R, \mathcal{B}(R), P)$? But they have different support?

Comment: For coupling you want random variables $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.  The "support" does not matter. Perhaps $X$ has a Gaussian distribution and $Y$ has a  Bernoulli distribution. **Every** random variable has **some** distribution.  So take any two random variables $X$ and $Y$ on the same prob space, they have some distributions $\mu$ and $v$ respectively, so the 2-tuple $(X,Y)$ can be viewed as a coupling of $\mu$ and $v$. Perhaps your book is overemphasizing the unnecessary concept "support."

Comment: Thank you! In my example, the coupling $(X,Y)$ of $\mu$ and $\nu$ whose law $\pi$ is concentrated on the graph of a measurable function $T: [0,1]\to [a,b]$. Does it mean that $\pi$ is a probability measure on $[0,1]\times [a,b]$? So can we say that the graph $Y=T(X)$ is the coupling $\pi$? (I also add the graph of $Y=T(X)$.)

Comment: Given any probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$, any random variables
$X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and any Borel measurable subset $B \subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $P[(X,Y) \in B]>0$, we can define a measure $\mu:\mathcal{B}(B)\rightarrow [0,1]$ by 
$$ \mu(A) = \frac{P[(X,Y) \in A]}{P[(X,Y)\in B]} \quad \forall A \in \mathcal{B}(B)$$
where $\mathcal{B}(B)$ is the set of all Borel measurable subsets of $B$.  This includes cases when $Y=T(X)$ for some measurable function $T$, and/or when $P[(X,Y)\in B]=1$.

Comment: To fix ideas it makes sense to just say that a coupling between two distributions $v_1$ and $v_2$ is an ordered pair of random variables $(X,Y)$ where $X$ has distribution $v_1$ and $Y$ has distribution $v_2$.  So the coupling is the ordered pair $(X,Y)$. If $Y=T(X)$ then indeed the coupling is the ordered pair $(X, T(X))$.

Comment: Can we say $\pi$ is a probability measure on $[0,1]\times [a,b]$, right? Of course, we can also say $\pi$ is a probability measure on $R\times R$.

Comment: Also, for the order pair $(X, T(X))$, does it satisfy the constrain of the coupling so that $\pi(A\times R)=\mu(A), \pi(R\times B)=\nu(B)$ for all measurable sets $A, B\subset R$? I am not confused how to verify this condition? Is it ok to write $\pi=(Id, T)_{\#}\mu$ for verifying marginal condition?

Comment: If $P[(X,Y) \in [0,1]\times [a,b]]=1$ you can use that set as the set $B$ I mentioned above, that is, $B=[0,1]\times [a,b]$. Also $\pi(A \times \mathbb{R}) = P[(X,Y) \in A \times \mathbb{R}] = P[X\in A]$.  It is just a fancy way of saying that $X$ has a certain distribution.

Comment: Thank you! But why do you need to add this condition $P((X,Y)\in [0,1]\times [a,b])=1$? Since $Y=T(X)$ for a measurable function $T: [0,1]\mapsto [a,b]$. We absolutely have $P(((X,Y)\in [0,1]\times [a,b])=1$, right? Because $(X, Y)$ is just defined on this product space.

Comment: The above can be applied to general problems that satisfy that condition, including problems like yours.